# Date to Weeknum in Access/Excel/VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date, pivot

I have an access-file, that I imported in excel as a PivotTable. I want the possibility to sort the data in a slicer as Week numbers. I have grouped and set days to 7, but that only gives me 2020-01-01 - 2020-01-07 for example.

Should I convert the weeknum's already in Access? And then, how do I do that?
Please explain it all, even where to paste the code and how to implement it in Access.

Thank you.

Comment: It maybe does. But I really don't know where to put the code in the Access databasefile to make the column weeknum read and transform from the date-column on the same row.

Comment: Well, since the week number is needed in Excel, I would add it in Excel, after importing the data. I'm sure you can think of suitable cells, depending on the layout of your data. Note that your question (even in the header) is how to convert date to week number.